# Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE EXTENSION[*] IF NOT EXISTS UUID_OSSP "

Tags: java, h2

I'm trying to create h2 DB schema. Here is my sql

```
create extension if not exists uuid_ossp;

create table users
(
    user_id     uuid default uuid_generate_v4() not null,
    name        varchar(255),
    created_on  timestamp,
    modified_on timestamp
);

create table product
(
    product_id  uuid default uuid_generate_v4() not null,
    name        varchar(25),
    created_on  timestamp,
    modified_on timestamp
);

create table products_users
(
    user_id    uuid,
    product_id uuid
);
```

And I get an error

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in
>   SQL statement "CREATE EXTENSION[*] IF NOT EXISTS UUID_OSSP "; expected
>   "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA,
>   CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED,
>   LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, SYNONYM, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH,
>   SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement: create extension if not exists
>   uuid_ossp [42001-199]

Comment: Your PostgreSQL is missing a package and without it you will get this error so I suggest to install it before you run your code

Comment: @YCF_L I resolved problem with file, but it doesn't help to resolve SyntaxErrorException

Comment: h2 does not support that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by deleting `create extension if not exists uuid_ossp;` and adding `default random_uuid()` instead of `default uuid_generate_v4()` in tables.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when I tried with CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

like @annswerg tried, It was giving me following error,

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "
LINE 1: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

But it worked without any error when I ran following,

CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";

without IF NO EXIST,

And my postgresql version is PostgreSQL 10.15 (Ubuntu 10.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

Hope it helps someone who may face similar issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the create extension bit in your sql, and you want to use this in a test, you can put this in data.sql

**src/test/resources/data.sql**

```
CREATE ALIAS uuid_generate_v4 AS '
    UUID ez_uuid() {
        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
';
```